# No chance to release a ban because of missing existing posts, which could be improved

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

I've deleted two questions, so I've got a question ban.

But I've got only one other question, the people are absolutly not interesting in([Improve FloatBuffers' Performance with Native C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555830/improve-floatbuffers-performance-with-native-c-c)),although the question is well asked, so I can change It 1000 times and it won't change anything.

But, how to release the ban Now and what about people which have got only deleted Questions?

UPDATE:

I've earned good reputation for my question, so I was able release the ban.

Comment: Hmm, looks like a moderator has recently disagreed with you about that particular question being "well asked"...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer some questions to earn some reputation points.  Eventually, this should raise you above the ban threshold, and you will be able to ask questions again.

Comment: Good advice, but it catches my eye he says he only has *two* deleted questions. That really shouldn't put him into ban territory, considering that the other active question has only received one downvote, should it? Are the bans that sensitive?

Comment: @Cody: While the OP has only two deleted questions, it is 66% of his attempts, and the third question is now closed. The bans are carefully calibrated to statistical data collected from preexisting posts; that data shows that the odds of a new user being a good Stackizen after a user's first two questions have been closed drop dramatically.

Comment: @Cody: Also note that the OP is not restricted in any other way from using the site, except for asking questions.

Comment: Right, I knew that the bans were specific. I just didn't know they took effect when the statistical sample size was so limited.

Comment: So it's all about reputation? I mean, user with high reputation can't get the question ban even if he got all his reputation from suggesting edits, for example? I would expect the algorithm to just count votes - up vs. down.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: While I know how the Team came up with the algorithm, I don't know the exact details of the implementation, so I'm not qualified to comment on that.